# How to execute different where conditions in a better way

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I wrote a stored procedure to fetch data from a table for my application. Now I need to query the same columns using another condition. I used `IF ELSE` for resolving the issue my current stored procedure is like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sample]
      @flag INT=1 
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    IF(@flag = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            item1, item2, item3
        FROM 
            table1 
        WHERE 
            (my first condition)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            item1, item2, item3
        FROM 
            table1 
        WHERE 
            (my second condition)
    END
END
```

The current stored procedure is working fine but its dirty if I have to need another column or I need to remove a column, I have to do that twice.

Is there any way to optimize this stored procedure? I'm new to SQL and this is kind of my first stored procedure. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can something like this:

```
SELECT item1,item2,item3
FROM table1
WHERE 
  (@flag = 1 and 'my first condition') OR
  (@flag != 1 and 'my secondcondition')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE for that

```
SELECT item1, item2, item3
FROM table1
WHERE 
   CASE 
       WHEN @flag = 1 AND 'my first condition' THEN 1
       WHEN @flag != 1 AND 'my second condition' THEN 1
   END = 1
```